# Azure Active Directory authentication in Rust

Tags: azure, rust, azure-active-directory

Does anyone have experience with Microsoft's Azure Active Directory authentication in Rust?
I've built a service at work that has LDAP authentication support, but we now need to deploy said application at a client that doesn't use LDAP. They've advised us to look at Active Directory Federated Services and Azure Active Directory.

I've been researching, and it seems like Microsoft mainly provides an [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) (ADAL) for popular languages/frameworks, with no barebones documentation that I can find.

Does anyone know a resource/online documentation that I could follow? I'm looking for some generic REST API that I could implement with `request` or `hyper`.

Comment: Please note that *"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* ([SO/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). You could ask your question in the [user-forum](https://users.rust-lang.org) instead.

Comment: I think there is no official library at least. But AAD supports OpenID Connect, it's used in most new apps. There might be a library for OpenID Connect authentication for Rust? You can find general protocol documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually sure, you can refer to the offical document [`Azure REST API Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) to know how to register a client application with Azure AD and to authenticate for calling a REST API in Rust with `request` or `hyper`. I think it's your real want.

Otherwise, Python is a good embedded scripting language for Rust. Uf you can use ADAL for Python to get access token via authentication, I think a good workaround is to use some cargo modules like [`PyO3/pyo3`](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3) or [`dgrunwald/rust-cpython`](https://github.com/dgrunwald/rust-cpython) to call a Python script for authenticating with AAD from Rust code.